# Sorting dates using Solr is messing up some dates

Tags: java, sorting, date, solr

I'm having a weird problem while sorting dates using Solr.
The thing is, when I sort it, it's ok if we only have dates like: 01/01/2011, 01/02/2011, 01/03/2011

but if we have dates typed wrong by mistake like: 01/01/2011, 01/02/2011, 01/03/2011, **01/04/0011** and null values as well, then we have a problem
It's mixing everything.

Is there a range that Solr works. It's not a invalid date, it's just a date that passed a long time ago, but still valid.

Any ideas that could maybe help me?

Sorry if I didn't give many details, I'm still new using it. Anything else, just ask and I'll try to detail it better.

**UPDATE**

Field is like this on schema.xml

```
<field name="endDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get that 01/04/0011 at the beginning? Where you want that null values?

Comment: The null values should come before the 01/04/0011. and yes, the 01/04/0011 at the beginning

Comment: Could you add field type definition from schema?

Answer (score 5):

If you are not running latest Solr 3.5 you might hit at least 2 bugs :)
But first, to get missing (null) values at the beginning you might try to set:

```
sortMissingLast=false
sortMissingFirst=true
```

on the tdate fieldtype definition ([SchemaXml Doc](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)). This is new feature in Solr 3.5 [SOLR-2881](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2881)

Second problem are dates between years 0001-1000 this is documented as issue [SOLR-2772](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2772)

More about releases: [Apache Solr Release Notes](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_5_0/solr/CHANGES.txt)

If you are running some older version of Solr and you can't upgrade, or my suggestions are not working for you, there is always another way :) Reindex your data, but as sint timestamp.

Comment: I gave this options to the manager, let's see what he thinks about it. Thank you very much!! Once we have the answer, I'll mark your answer